# How to create Xml file in memory to upload on the server

Tags: c#, .net, file-upload, ftpwebrequest

I want to transfer XML from client to some server using `FTP`. What I get is the `XmlElement` object. I know that I can create the `File` and upload it to appropriate location (FTP).

However, I think it's better to create `File` in memory (to avoid file saving on the local disk).

Can someone guide me how can i achieve this?

I am using C# 4.0.

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683189/possible-to-write-xml-to-memory-with-xmlwriter)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [FtpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.outerxml.aspx) to write directly to the request stream without first saving the file on disk

> Retrieves the stream used to upload data to an FTP server.

[XmlElement.OuterXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.outerxml.aspx) returns a String representation of the XmlElement.

```
string xml = myXmlElement.OuterXml;
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
requestStream.Close();
```

Comment: @Erirc J. : FtpWebRequest.Write() method's first argument is of type `byte[]`. It's not of the string type which `OuterXml` property of the `XmlElement` returns. So your code will not work.

Answer (score 2):

Ling2Xml is easier to use:

```
stream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream();

XElement xDoc = new XElement("Root",
                    new XElement("Item1", "some text"),
                    new XElement("Item2", new XAttribute("id", 666))
                    );

xDoc.Save(stream);
```

or you can use `serialization`

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SomeItem));
ser.Serialize(stream, new SomeItem());

public class SomeItem
{
    public string Name;
    public int ID;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@L.B. gave the hint to use `XDocument` and it solved my problem.

Here is the solution:

- Write a code to create `XDocument` object out of the `XmlElement` object.

  ```
  StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  XmlWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(stringBuilder));
  xmlElement.WriteTo(xmlWriter);
  XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
  xmlDocument.Load(new StringReader(stringBuilder.ToString()));
  XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlDocument.CreateNavigator().ReadSubtree(), LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
  ```
- Then use the FTP's stream like this.

  ```
  Stream ftpstream = ((FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(path)).GetRequestStream();    
   doc.Save(ftpstream);

  ftpstream.Close();
  ```